# Why android internet server receive strange characters?

Tags: android

I have one server and one client.

That client only send server a string.

Here are my code:

Server MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.t1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        Thread sThread = new Thread(new TCPServer());
        sThread.start();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Server TCPServer.java

```
package com.example.t1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TCPServer implements Runnable
{   
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8005;

    public void run() {
         try {
              Log.d("TCP", "S: Connecting...");

              ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
              while (true) {
                  Log.d("TCP", "S: begin to accept");
                  Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                  Log.d("TCP", "S: Receiving...");
                  try {
                      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                      String str = in.readLine();
                      Log.d("TCP", "S: Received: '" + str + "'");                      
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
                    } finally {
                        client.close();
                        Log.d("TCP", "S: Done.");
                    }
              }          

         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
         }
    }
}
```

Client :

```
package com.example.internet_client;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{


    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8888;
    TextView tv;
    Socket socket = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        InetAddress serverAddr = null;
        SocketAddress sc_add = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        //要傳送的字串
        String message = "123";

        try {
            //設定Server IP位置
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.3.25");
            //設定port:1234
            sc_add= new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr,8005);

            socket = new Socket();
            //與Server連線，timeout時間2秒
            Log.d("TCP", "Client: begin to connect");
            socket.connect(sc_add,2000);
            Log.d("TCP", "Client: begin to write");
            //傳送資料
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF(message);

            //關閉socket
            socket.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "InetAddress物件建立失敗",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "socket建立失敗",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "傳送失敗",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

It shows the strange characters.

[image]

What's happened?

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

When you write objects to a `DataOutputStream`, it includes extra data that a `DataInputStream` can read back out later. If you just want write a String to an output stream as bytes, use an `OutputStreamWriter`.